# multiline template in directive definition

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am trying to make a directive template multiline. Is this possible?

```
myApp.directive('myDir', function() {
return {
    restrict: 'E',        
    template: '<div>
                |Hello,
                |{{test}}!
                |</div>'
    };
});
```

Here's a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4n7YH/) to see what I mean.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use "\" at the end of each line.

```
myApp.directive('myDir', function() {
return {
    restrict: 'E',        
    template: '<div>\
                |Hello,\
                |{{test}}!\
                |</div>'
};
```

Here's you [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2kT6n/)

Comment: Be careful with this. Because it's not a part of ECMAScript! -> https://github.com/jgable/open-source/blob/master/styleguides/JavaScript/language-rules.md#multiline-string-literals

Answer (score 4):

I just learned you could use the symbol below the tilde (`) for multi-line template,

```
myApp.directive('myDir', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',        
        template: `<div>
                |Hello,
                |{{test}}!
                |</div>`
    };
});
```

Comment: The symbol used to enclose multi-line string is backtick (`) and is part of ES 2015 standard, more information can be found here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27678052/what-is-the-usage-of-the-backtick-symbol-in-javascript

Answer (score 3):

You could also make use of the JavaScript function [`join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) to achieve this, which I think looks better.

```
myApp.directive('myDir', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        template: ['<div>',
            'Hello, ',
            '{{test}}!',
            '</div>'].join(''),
    };
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5c6fct7v/1/) is here (I removed the `|`'s to make it look better).

Answer (score 3):

You could also concatenate individual strings:

```
myApp.directive('myDir', function() {
return {
    restrict: 'E',        
    template: '<div>' +
            'Hello,' + 
            '{{test}}!' +
            '</div>'
    };
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use graves instead of single quotes

```
myApp.directive('myDir', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',        
    template: `<div>
        Hello, 
        {{test}}!
        </div>`
  };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can concatenate individual strings **and** put the pluses at the start of each line, instead of at the end. This works out nicely if you use a 4-space tabstop: `template` is 8 characters long, so all the pluses will line up right below the colon.

```
myApp.directive('myDir', function() {
return {
    restrict: 'E',        
    template: '<div>'
            + 'Hello, '
            + '{{test}}!'
            + '</div>'
    };
});
```

Here's the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/imoskvin/60cjesq2/3/).

Comment: It's surprisingly difficult to find information on whether JavaScript cares if you put the plus at the end of the trailing line or at the start of the next one. If someone has a definitive source, please share. Tested in FF, Chrome, IE 11. I figure if it wasn't always the case, that syntactic change happened a long, long time ago.